# How can I implement a RESTful service that accepts an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I'm new to this so any advice is appreciated.  I am trying to implement a RESTful service that accepts XML formatted data as input.

My ServiceContract looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBlaService<T>
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/", Method = "POST")]
    void CreateBla(XmlDocument xmldoc);
}
```

And I end up with this when I try to use the service:

*Type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute*

Is there a serializeable xml document implementation I should be using?

thanks for any suggestions.

-Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the XmlDocument type is no serializable, the XmlElement type is, so you can pass that instead. From a discussion found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c82e3ed2-0090-4978-8195-12ba7df79dc5/). There's an extended sample on that page.

This seems really obnoxious...maybe somebody else here can tell us *why* an XmlDocument is not serializable?

Comment: It's a whole document, including processing instructions, DTD, etc. You can't put an XML document in the middle of another XML document (like a SOAP envelope). It doesn't make much sense. How tough is it to use `XmlElement`?